# Show that the complex closed line integral $\oint\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{p(z)}$ is $0$ ($p$ is polynomial)

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, contour-integration

Let $p$ be a polynomial of degree $n\geq2$ and has $n$ **different** roots $z_1,\dots,z_n$.

Prove that $\oint\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{p(z)}=0$ where the closed path is large enough so that all roots are in the interior of the path.

I need this as a lemma to a question that was asked in complex analysis. I tried to think of something clever to do using the [Argument Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle#Applications_and_consequences) but couldn't find a function whose [logarithmic derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative) would be proportional to $\frac{1}{p}$. I thought something along the lines of $p \cdot p^{(1)} \cdot p^{(2)} \cdot \dots \cdot p^{(n)}$ would work but had a bunch of things "left over" in the enumerator that ruined it.

That's where I'm at...

Comment: The integral is independent of the path, as long as it encloses all zeros of $p$. Take a LARGE circle with centre $0$.

Comment: But why would that make the integral equal 0? It's not holomorphic in the interior of the circle as it has $n$ simple poles there

Comment: Reverse the orientation by using the $z\mapsto {1\over z}$ and integrate around infinity.

Comment: You can also see this by considering two arbitary contours that encircle all the poles. The difference between the two can be written as a contour integral constructed from both contours such that the interior of the innermost is left out from the interior of the combined contour. This means that there are no poles in the combined contour, therefore the two contour integrals are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change coordinates: map

$$z\mapsto {1\over z}=\xi,\quad -{d\xi\over \xi^2} = dz$$

Then you have the integral around a large circle, $C_R$ transformed into

$$\oint_{C_{1/R}}{d\xi\over \xi^2p({1\over\xi})}$$

By the Cauchy estimate we have

$$\left|\oint_{C_{1/r}}{d\xi\over \xi^2p({1\over\xi})}\right|\le {2\pi\over R}\cdot R^2\cdot\sup_{\xi\in C_{1/R}}\left|p\left({1\over\xi}\right)\right|\le {C\over R}$$

because $\text{deg}(p)\ge 2$.

The way to see this is zero immediately is that, since $z=\infty$ is *not* a simple pole (since $\text{deg } p\ge 2$) there is no residue at infinity.

Comment: Very clean, thanks

Answer (score 1):

List the roots of $p$ as $z_1,\dots,z_n$, using the fundamental theorem of algebra. Let $r=\max |z_n|$. If you now integrate around any circle of radius $R>r$ centered at 0, the integral will be

$$2 \pi i \sum_{k=1}^n \text{Res} \left ( \frac{1}{p},z_k \right )$$

which does not depend on $R$. Now the triangle inequality gives us that $|p(z)| \geq c_1 R^n - c_2 R^{n-1}$ if $|z|=R$, so by an ML estimate we have that the integral is at most $\frac{2 \pi R}{c_1 R^n - c_2 R^{n-1}} \to 0$ as $R \to \infty$. But the integral does not depend on $R$, so it must be zero.

Answer (score 0):

A direct estimate works as well. Note that the fact that the roots of $p$ are distinct is irrelevant, the degree of $p$ is what matters.

Let $n \ge 2$ be the degree of $p$. Choose $L$ so that for some $K>0$ we have $|p(z)| \ge K |z|^n$ for all $|z| \ge L$. Note that $z \mapsto { 1 \over p(z)}$ is analytic on $B(0,L)^c$.

Let $\gamma_R(t) = R e^{i 2 \pi t}$

If $R,R' \ge L$, then $\gamma_R,\gamma_{R'}$ are homotopic on $B(0,L)^c$.
Hence we have $\int_{\gamma_R} {dz \over p(z)} = \int_{\gamma_{R'}} {dz \over p(z)}$.

If $R,R' \ge L$, we have 
$|\int_{\gamma_R'} {dz \over p(z)} | = |\int_{\gamma_R} {dz \over p(z)} | = |\int_0^1 {\gamma_R'(t) \over p(\gamma_R(t)) } dt |  \le \int_0^1 |{\gamma_R'(t) \over p(\gamma_R(t)) }| dt \le 2 \pi {R \over K R^n}$.

Since $R\ge L$ was arbitrary, we see that $\int_{\gamma_R'} {dz \over p(z)} = 0$.

Comment: Yeah, the fact that the roots are distinct is relevant to the rest of the question which I didn't present here. I just didn't want to leave it out in case it somehow is needed